# I want my service to work once every day, but it is working multiple times instead

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to create an app where it decrements an integer value by 1 each day at a specific time. To do that, I am using a BroadcastReceiver which supposedly gets activated at 12 am. And from the BroadcastReceiver, I am calling a service which creates a background thread to modify the value in the database (MySQL database) and then closes the service. **The problem is that the values are being decremented by 1 multiple times a day instead of only once.** Here is the code:

**Manifest**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".myAlarm"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"></receiver>

<service android:name=".myService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" />
```

**Main**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, myAlarm.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

**MyAlram (BroadcastReceiver)**

```
public class myAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), myService.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), myService.class));
            }
    }

}
```

**myService (Service)**

```
public class myService extends Service{

    private DBWorkers mydb;
    private Thread backgroundThread;
    private Context context;
    private Boolean isRunning = false;

    /**
     * Called by the system when the service is first created.  Do not call this method directly.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.context = this;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mydb = new DBWorkers(context);

            ArrayList<Worker> myList = new ArrayList<>(mydb.getAllWorkersService());
            ArrayList<Worker> newList = new ArrayList<>();

            //visa and work are the values I need to decrement daily
            for(Worker item : myList){
                int work = item.getWork(), visa = item.getVisa();

                if(visa > 0)
                {
                    visa = visa - 1;
                }
                else if(visa < 0)
                {
                    visa = 0;
                }

                if(work > 0)
                {
                    work = work - 1;
                }
                else if(work < 0)
                {
                    work = 0;
                }

                if(item.getVisa() != visa || item.getWork() != work){
                    newList.add(new Worker(item.getName(), visa, work, item.getId()));
                }
            }

            mydb.updateAllWorkers(newList);

            stopSelf();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        if (!isRunning){
            isRunning = true;
            backgroundThread.start();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed.  The
     * service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered
     * receivers, etc) at this point.  Upon return, there will be no more calls
     * in to this Service object and it is effectively dead.  Do not call this method directly.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**I also have few other questions:**

**1)** Is it better for me to use IntentService rather than a normal service? and why?

**2)** I do not know what is happening in the code below. I copy pasted it from an answer online because my code was not working on my phone and I think it is because my phone's os is 8.0 and this was the solution suggested. I would really appreciate your help by explaining it to me.

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
```

**3)** Do I need to make a background thread to run this task, or will it automatically be executed on a background thread since the app will most likely be killed?

**Thank you so much!**

Comment: To answer some of your side questions (1) I would. An Intent service will automatically start when you send it an intent, and then automatically shut down when it runs out of intents to process, thus handling your stopSelf logic automatically, (2) starting with Oreo, notifications need to be assigned to a channel. Users can see these channels in your app's settings, and they can modify sound/vibration/etc. settings for each channel. In your code, you are creating a channel but not setting it (either pass the channelId into the Builder constructor, or call setChannelId on the Builder).

Comment: @fpsulli3 Thank you! That is really helpful. Regarding the second question though. Do I need to add notifications to the services for them to work or I can remove the code and It will work fine?

Comment: It depends. In order for your app to run services, it needs to be in the foreground. In order to foreground your app without actually displaying the UI, you can run a foreground service (as you have done). A foreground service must show a persistent notification. However, if you're okay with your service running only when your app's UI is visible, you can run it as a background service without a notification.

Comment: Also, to answer your 3rd question, services run on the main thread by default. From the Service docs: "Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process." So if you want something to run on a background thread, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you @fpsulli3! Your answers have been helpful to me.